# How does one import symbols from a .fla file to an AIR project in FlashDevelop?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flashdevelop

This is my first time working with AIR. In previous AS3 projects in FlashDevelop, I would create a .fla file with Flash Professional in the same directory as my source files and link my main class as the document class. I used Flash to create symbols and export them for actionscript and then wrote the definitions in FlashDevelop. That isn't working with AIR.

I have the .fla file in the same directory with all of my source files. FlashDevelop AIR Mobile compiles the project fine, but the application is a white screen. Compiling the same project with the same compiler in Flash Professional works perfectly, showing all of the symbols.

How do I access the symbols in my .fla file if I am compiling from FlashDevelop?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

In Flash Professional, go to your publish settings.  Check the .swc box to export a swc when you publish (and make sure the export location is in one of your flash develop project sub folders. A subfolder called 'lib' is common practice).  Also, if desired, uncheck other outputs in your publish settings.

[image: Export Your FlashPro Project as a SWC]
Publish your .fla.

In Flash Develop, find the .swc in the project panel directory tree,  right click it, and choose "Add to Library"   You may also need to right-click again and choose "options" and tell it to "Include completely".
[image: Tell FlashDevelop To Include the SWC]

Now all the symbols from your .fla are available to your FlashDevelop project.

Comment: @quantomworks - can you be more specific?   This makes all your classes available in FlashDevelop.   So if you have a MovieClip in your Flash/Animate library, and exported it for actionscript,  and followed these instructions, you could instantiate it in FlashDevelop.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say was would this work for exporting everything in an .fla? I am at the poit in my project where it is taking too long to compile everything and my vpn is messing up so I cant remote into my desktop at home for quicker compile times. I need a production server and I am looking for the fastest solution possible to let me have a command line compiler handle my code and my elements in my frames of my .fla. Some are movieclips that I summon but thers aleady exist on the stage.

Comment: I am trying to use something like Jenkins to get things moving again [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046418/supplying-compiler-constants-using-jenkins-to-build-an-adobe-air-project] but I would need to have my project command line ready.

Comment: I'd recommend asking a new question (if you can get it specific enough).  .swc files do not include the main timeline,  just whatever is in the library exported for actionscript.  I've never tried to integrate Adobe Animate with command line tools, but it can likely be done since IDE's like FlashDevelop can seems to trigger Animate's compile/publish commands.

Comment: Will do. Yeah it turned into a question as I was typing it. Let me do a little more research and I'll post one if it comes to that. Thanks.